# SSIS; Is it better than writing code?

Tags: ssis

I have a ETL project, that has alot of data that needs cleaning. We're talking about alot of complex transformations. The process needs to take place nightly, and has to finish within a certain amount of time (10 hours). To this end it is best that the ETL use all the processor cores on the system.

Which would be better to use to perform complex ETL transforms in a multi processor environment:

SSIS

or

Dot Net Framework 4 (let me qualify that. I can write and application using entity framework and parallel tasks to do the complex data transforms that are required. Writing an application to do the ETLing isn't a problem, however I'm trying to use **the best tool** for the job.)

I know it's an unfair question; that SSIS is a technology and dot net is a framework but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll say no.

i started to write an ETL job, and got stymied by the first column of data: a formatted date time. SSIS was unable to make heads or tails of it.

Perhaps you can spent weeks trying to figure out how to convince SSIS to do what you want - but it's much easier just to get it done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, working with SSIS is a chore and every project for which I have used it has amazed me by how much longer it took than expected. To be fair, I suppose that a solution to most any problem eventually could be fashioned using either one ***given enough time***.

Using either tool usually involves doing some research and learning in each project. Learning about .NET leaves me edified. Struggling with patchy work-arounds and arcane code hacks to make SSIS work leaves me deflated.

What could be more elementary in software coding than reading from and writing to variables in memory? How complex could it possibly be in any language? How many restrictions on what, when, and where could there be on performing such a rudimentary task? To find the answer, search the internet for the phrase "ssis write to variables in script". SSIS takes complexity to a whole new level, even for the simplest of operations! God help you if you have to write to a package variable within a data flow task.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is a tool specifically for doing the job you mention.  It's ideal for ETL processing and has a lot of common tasks built-in; in a custom .Net framework you'd have to code these from scratch.

Comment: It's true that I'll have to do them from scratch in .net but at least I'll be able to do them. I know that SSIS can call .net stuff however I'm worried that it isn't optimized for Parallel processing.

Comment: SSIS has parallel processing built-in and by using the MaxConcurrentExecutables package propery, you can exert some control over this.  Is your question more to do with what is better for you personally to use, given your skill-set, rather than what is actually the best tool to use for an ETL solution?  SSIS does have a bit of a learning curve, but it is worth it for this sort of task.

Comment: The question is around best tool for an ETL, of this nature. I've only built 1 ETL in the past and that was with .net. I had built it with .net because DTS wasn't able to do the complex transforms that I needed. Also I was limited then by my skill set. This time the transforms are even more complex but SSIS has evolved. I've seen SSIS used before and it seems to be a chore.